# Unity Tango app crashing when using FindPlane function

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, google-project-tango

Recently I've started porting my older Unity code with an earlier version of the Tango / Unity SDK to the latest version.  Overall, it's working great.  Faster frame rate, less drift, everything seems pretty good....Until: BLAM... Sudden crash.  So, I tried paring down my app to the essentials to see if I could reproduce the crash and what I've found is that if I follow the AR Unity example in the docs to the letter, no problem.  But, if I add a 'FindPlane' call within the Update() function so I place a sphere at the planeCenter of whatever is at 960,600 (middle of screen), after a few minutes the app will crash.  So my suspicion is that this is what's causing the crash in my larger app (with many more moving parts, so to speak).

My question is two part:

1) can anyone suggest some debugging processes to help me identify exactly what the problem is here, in case it isn't the FindPlane function after all?

2) does anyone know why the FindPlane function might cause an error?  Even if it doesn't successfully find a point it should still return Vector3.zero and a new/default Plane object, neither of which should result in a crash.

Thank you for your thoughts on this perplexing issue.

EDIT: I tried installing and activating Tango-Debug-Overlay recently and it shows a bit of diagnostic info.  The problem appears to be thermal, and from what I can tell, related to the depth sensor.  So now I'm trying to set a very low FPS, as a test, and disabling the depth sensor between frames, to see if that has any impact.  I will post updates as I find out info.

Comment: maybe it is better to  ask the question on the tango forum

Comment: Thanks @tim, would you mind clarifying how I would specify which forum to post this question to?  I thought my selection of tags would sort that out but I guess not? I tried changing the order of the tags but it didn't actually update them to the order specified.

Comment: maybe try project tango: [google +](https://plus.google.com/communities/114537896428695886568) and your tag is ok